# what happens when tracking pixels fail to load properly via google tag manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

If I add a tracking pixel that suddenly 404s or contains an error, does the parent page still load normally? Will some browsers hang with a perpetual 'loading' indicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 404 would never result in a permanent loading indicator (after all a 404 is a pretty definitive response). If by "pixel" you mean an actual image then a 404 will not affect the original page (other than the a browsers network tab will show the error, but this will only be visible to developers).

If you mean "tracking pixel" generically for tracking script and include Javascript tracking tags the answer is only marginally different - a 404 will not affect page load, but if your site calls a function that is included in the external file then there will be problems.

If a script you include directly in GTM throws an error GTM will not allow you to publish the tag in question (however logical errors and variable name collisions are very much possible).

If an error is introduced in a linked (i.e. loaded from a remote location) 3rd party script the script it will affect the parent page - GTM does not check linked scripts, and they will behave no differently as if they were linked directly in the source code. The nature of the error will depend on the script, so as a second worst case the hosting page will die (the real worst case is if this is not an error but an malicious attack that injects javascript that runs in the context of the page - in that case the script might steal cookies, send you clients credit cards numbers to scammers and deface your website. Many people don't seem aware of this, so I thought I just mention it).

Comment: The concern is with external third-party js files with no errors at the time of the tag publication, but have an error introduced later. What happens then? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Updated the answer, see last paragraph.